# Obtener registro en un rango de 9.5 horas de el dia en curso

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo la siguiente consulta en mysql con la cual genero un reporte en excel de todo lo registrado en el turno de 6-3:30 y de 3:30-12 el reporte de 6-3:30 si me lo genera bien y me lo manda por correo y el reporte tiene la informacion que requiero, pero el reporte de 3:30-12 el archivo en excel me lo muestra vacio no obtiene ningun registro me podrian ayudar a saber a que se debe

Mi tabla tiene la columna horaEscaneo_ma y fechaEscaneo_ma y mi consulta la tengo de la siguiente manera.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM material_recv WHERE horaEscaneo_ma > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9.5 HOUR) AND fechaEscaneo_ma > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY horaEscaneo_ma ASC"
```

Codigo PHP

```
<?php
require_once "config.php";

require_once "PHPMailer-master/src/PHPMailer.php";
require_once 'PHPMailer-master/src/SMTP.php';
require_once 'PHPMailer-master/src/Exception.php';

//Para generar archivo Excel
require 'ClassesPhpExcel/PHPExcel.php';

//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
  
  
$spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0)

->setCellValue('A1', 'UserEtiquetadora')
->setCellValue('B1', 'No.Material')
->setCellValue('C1', 'No.Serial')
->setCellValue('D1', 'Qty.Serie')
->setCellValue('E1', 'Bodega Serie')
->setCellValue('F1', 'Tipo de Material')
->setCellValue('G1', 'Fecha Recibo')
->setCellValue('H1', 'Hora Recibo')
->setCellValue('I1', 'Fecha de registro')
->setCellValue('J1', 'Hora Registro')
->setCellValue('K1', 'No.Reloj')
->setCellValue('L1', 'Hora Escaneo')
->setCellValue('M1', 'Fecha Escaneo');

$spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1:M1')
            ->getFont()->setBold(true);
  
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM material_recv WHERE horaEscaneo_ma > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 9.5 HOUR) AND fechaEscaneo_ma > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY horaEscaneo_ma ASC");

if($query->num_rows > 0) {
    $i = 2;
    while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
        $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()
        ->setCellValue('A'.$i , $row['userName_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$i , $row['materialNumber_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$i , $row['serialNumber_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('D'.$i , $row['cantidadSerie_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('E'.$i , $row['bodegaSerie_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('F'.$i , $row['tipoMaterial_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('G'.$i , $row['fechaRecibo_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('H'.$i , $row['horaRecibo_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('I'.$i , $row['fechaRegistro_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('J'.$i , $row['horaRegistro_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('K'.$i , $row['usuarioReloj_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('L'.$i , $row['horaEscaneo_ma'])
        ->setCellValue('M'.$i , $row['fechaEscaneo_ma']);
        $i++;
    }
}
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Excel2007');
$filename = 'PRECONTEOFINDETURNO_'.date('YmdHis').'.xlsx';
  
if (!file_exists('files')) {
    mkdir('files', 0755);
}
$objWriter->save('files/'.$filename);
  
// send as an attachment
try {

    $toAddress = [
        [
            'address' => 'jessica.chaparro@sewsus.com.mx',
            'name' => 'Jessica Chaparro',
        ]

    ];

    $ccAddress = [
        [
            'add' => 'alberto.cruzloera@sewsus.com.mx',
            'nam' => 'Alberto Cruz',
        ],
    ];

    $bodyMessage = [ 

    'subject' => '< Reporte 1 Año Revision Recibos >< Preconteo >< Sistema Etiquetado V2.2 >',
    'body' => '
    <div>
        <br><br>
        <table>
            <tbody>
            <td><strong>Reporte fin de turno:</strong></td></tr>
            <td>Buen dia Dalila</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td> Se genero correctamente el Reporte</td>
            <tr>
            <td>De 1 año </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td>Saludos!</td>
            </tr>
                    
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <i><u>Por favor, no responda este mensaje</u></i>
        </div>
        <div>
            <i><u>webmaster:</u></i>
            <a href="mailto:alberto.cruzloera@sewsus.com.mx">alberto.cruzloera@sewsus.com.mx</a>
        </div>

        Saludos!

    </div>',

    ];

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

    /*$mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->Host = '172.30.56.70';
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = 'notificacion-app@jmcmail.local';   //username
    $mail->Password = '0797';   //password
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->Priority = 1;
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = SMTP::DEBUG_CONNECTION;*/
  
    $mail->setFrom('notificacion-app@jmcmail.local', 'App reporte preconteo');
    $mail->addBCC('notificacion-app@jmcmail.local', 'App reporte preconteo');
    
    foreach ($toAddress as $address)
                    $mail->addAddress($address['address'], $address['name']);

                foreach ($ccAddress as $item)
                    $mail->addCC($item['add'], $item['nam']);
  
    $mail->addAttachment('files/'.$filename);
  
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject = $bodyMessage['subject'];
    $mail->Body    = $bodyMessage['body'];
  
    $mail->send();
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Anexo imagen de mysql y del reporte en blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si la consulta es relativa a `now()` el resultado dependerá de la hora en que se ejecute.

Comment: La tarea se esta ejecutando a las 11:50 PM y el correo llega en aproximadamente 2 min pero con el reporte en blanco

Comment: ¿Estás seguro de los intervalos? 6+9.5 = 15.5(15:30), y 15.5+9.5 = 25(01:00), lo que significa que los turnos son desiguales o que el segundo turno termina el día siguiente o que los intervalos que pones son incorrectos.

Comment: Si estoy de acuerdo con tigo pero al ejecutarlo la consulta tomara el rango de hora desde la hora en que se ejecute el archivo php por ejemplo si lo corro a las 7 pm me mostrara todos los registros en un rango de 9.5 hrs apartir de la hora en que se ejecuto el archivo osea que si lo corro a las 11:50 pm me mostrara todo los registros en un rango de 9.5 tengo el mismo codigo con otra tabla de un sistema diferente y en ese si me manda informacion y se ejecuta a la misma hora que este.

Comment: A menos que este mal utilizado este intervalo `AND fechaEscaneo_ma > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY`, ya que la fecha y la hora se registran por separado use el intervalo de `1 DAY`

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener los registros del turno de 3:30 a 12:00 podrías cambiar la condición del WHERE de la siguiente manera:

$query = "SELECT * FROM material_recv WHERE horaEscaneo_ma >= '03:30:00' AND horaEscaneo_ma < '12:00:00' AND fechaEscaneo_ma = CURDATE() ORDER BY horaEscaneo_ma ASC"

De esta manera estarías seleccionando todos los registros que tengan una horaEscaneo_ma mayor o igual a las 3:30 y menor a las 12:00 del día actual.

Si deseas incluir también los registros del día anterior, puedes cambiar la condición de la fechaEscaneo_ma de la siguiente manera:

$query = "SELECT * FROM material_recv WHERE horaEscaneo_ma >= '03:30:00' AND horaEscaneo_ma < '12:00:00' AND (fechaEscaneo_ma = CURDATE() OR fechaEscaneo_ma = CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY horaEscaneo_ma ASC"

Con esta consulta estarías seleccionando todos los registros que tengan una horaEscaneo_ma mayor o igual a las 3:30 y menor a las 12:00 del día actual o del día anterior.

Espero que esto te ayude a resolver tu problema. Si tienes alguna duda o necesitas más ayuda no dudes en preguntar o comentar.

Comment: `$query = "SELECT * FROM material_recv WHERE horaEscaneo_ma >= '03:30:00' AND horaEscaneo_ma < '12:00:00' AND fechaEscaneo_ma = CURDATE() ORDER BY horaEscaneo_ma ASC"`, tengo duda en esta consulta pero que no al decirle que selecione todo lo menor a las 12, no me estaria descargando todo los registros incluyendo los de las 6-3:30

Comment: Nótese la diferencia entre 03:30 hrs (Tres horas y media después de media noche) y 15:30 hrs (Tres horas y media después de medio día).